# IOS Mobile Application is possible to develop in Windows 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, mobile-application

I like to develop IOS native mobile application using windows 7. Is it possible ? If it is possible kindly share the information ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No. You would need a Mac OS that has Xcode and iOS SDK to develop a native iOS app. You can build HTML5 apps and wrap it with PhoneGap using Windows 7 but to test it on a iOS device or simulator you would need a Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do native development on a Windows machine, you need a Mac.
You can do it with Mono/Xamarin/Icenium, though it won't be native.